# Add text right below the algorithms

Tags: footnotes, algorithm2e

I try to add some texts used to illustrate the algorithms right below the bottom line of algorithms.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[ruled]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[hang,flushmargin]{footmisc}
\usepackage{caption}
\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}
 \caption{How to write algorithms}\label{algorithm1}
 \KwIn{this text}
 \KwOut{how to write algorithm with \LaTeX2e }
 initialization\;
 \While{not at end of this document}{
  read current\;
  \eIf{understand}{
   go to next section\;
   current section becomes this one\;
   }{
   $y_0\leftarrow y$\;
  }
 }
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I want to add some text below the bottom line as shown below:

[image]

Based on [How to create footnote for algorithmicx's comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18443/how-to-create-footnote-for-algorithmicxs-comment), one should be using a `minipage`. I update my codes as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[ruled]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[hang,flushmargin]{footmisc}
\usepackage{caption}
\begin{document}
\noindent\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
\begin{algorithm}
 \caption{How to write algorithms}\label{algorithm1}\footnotetext{$y_0$ denotes the initial value.}
 \KwIn{this text}
 \KwOut{how to write algorithm with \LaTeX2e }
 initialization\;
 \While{not at end of this document}{
  read current\;
  \eIf{understand}{
   go to next section\;
   current section becomes this one\;
   }{
   $y_0\leftarrow y$\;
  }
 }
\end{algorithm}
\renewcommand\footnoterule{}
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

but errors occur.

Any suggestion will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The construction of [`algorithm2e`](http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithm2e)'s float is intricate, since it allows for specifying a stay-`H`ere-style float placement without the use of [`float`](http://ctan.org/pkg/float). Additionally it manages placement of captions at the top or bottom to suit different styles. So accommodate your request for a footnote inside this float you need to split it in somewhere where it will not influence the other components in the construction. Here's a patch that provides `\algorithmfootnote[<style>]{<stuff>}` (`<style>` defaults to `\footnotesize`):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[ruled]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath,caption}
\usepackage[hang,flushmargin]{footmisc}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\algorithmfootnote}[2][\footnotesize]{%
  \let\old@algocf@finish\@algocf@finish% Store algorithm finish macro
  \def\@algocf@finish{\old@algocf@finish% Update finish macro to insert "footnote"
    \leavevmode\rlap{\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
    #1#2
    \end{minipage}}%
  }%
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-3]
\begin{algorithm}[tb]
  \caption{How to write algorithms}\label{algorithm1}
  \algorithmfootnote{$y_0$ denotes the initial value.}
  \KwIn{this text}
  \KwOut{how to write algorithm with \LaTeX2e }
  initialization\;
  \While{not at end of this document}{
    read current\;
    \eIf{understand}{
      go to next section\;
      current section becomes this one\;
      }{
      $y_0 \leftarrow y$\;
    }
  }
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

`LaTeX Error: Not in outer par mode` results due to floating algorithm inside `minipage`. You can use `[H]` position specifier to escape from this situation. Also, I have put `\renewcommand\footnoterule{}` right after the `minipage` begins otherwise it is too late.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[ruled]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[hang,flushmargin]{footmisc}
\usepackage{caption}
\begin{document}
\noindent\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
\renewcommand\footnoterule{}                  %% This line should come here.
\begin{algorithm}[H]                          %% <-------------
 \caption{How to write algorithms}\label{algorithm1}\footnotetext{$y_0$ denotes the initial value.}
 \KwIn{this text}
 \KwOut{how to write algorithm with \LaTeX2e }
 initialization\;
 \While{not at end of this document}{
  read current\;
  \eIf{understand}{
   go to next section\;
   current section becomes this one\;
   }{
   $y_0\leftarrow y$\;
  }
 }
\end{algorithm}
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Of course, this removes the floaty-ness of the float.

Comment: @Harish: Thanks for pointing out the reasons why the error occurs.