# footnotes just after algorithm

Tags: floats, footnotes, algorithms

I am trying to add footnotes at the end of an algorithm environment (not at the end of the page). I found [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/156297/add-text-right-below-the-algorithms) where this is done but there are no numbers to refer to the footnote. So if I want to add several footnotes within an algorithm I need to be able to differentiate them. Is this remotely possible? I've seen people doing this for tables [here](http://texblog.org/2012/02/03/using-footnote-in-a-table/) and [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35615/footnote-in-table).

**UPDATE**

Following [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/156298/56716) I managed to do what I wanted. The following code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[noend]{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algorithmicx}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[hang,flushmargin]{footmisc}
\usepackage{caption}
\begin{document}
\noindent\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
\renewcommand\footnoterule{}                  %% This line should come here.
\begin{algorithmic}
\If {$i\geq maxval$}
    \State $i\gets 0$ \footnote{\label{note1}1\textsuperscript{st} footnote test}
\Else
    \If {$i+k\leq maxval$}
        \State $i\gets i+k$ \footnote{2\textsuperscript{nd} footnote test}
        \State $w\gets i$ 
    \EndIf
\EndIf
\end{algorithmic}
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

Gives me:

[image: result]

But I am still not done as I would like to refer to some existing footnote inside the algorithm. I then found [this other post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35043/reference-different-places-to-the-same-footnote) that can help me reference another footnote using `\footnotemark` command. However, I can't manage to get around the error:

```
./algorithm.tex:19: Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   \protect 
l.19 ...tate $w\gets i$ \footnotemark[\ref{note1}]
```

The new code I'm using now is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[noend]{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algorithmicx}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[hang,flushmargin]{footmisc}
\usepackage{caption}
\begin{document}
\noindent\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
\renewcommand\footnoterule{}                  %% This line should come here.
\begin{algorithmic}
\If {$i\geq maxval$}
    \State $i\gets 0$ \footnote{\label{note1}1\textsuperscript{st} footnote test}
\Else
    \If {$i+k\leq maxval$}
        \State $i\gets i+k$ \footnote{2\textsuperscript{nd} footnote test}
        \State $w\gets i$ \footnotemark[\ref{note1}]
    \EndIf
\EndIf
\end{algorithmic}
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Did you try wrapping your `algorithm` in a `minipage` environment?

Comment: Yes, I tried but nothing.

Comment: I have added a MWE that produces a footnote that's placed at the end of the page.

Comment: Your MWE is using the `savenotes` environment which has the explicit goal of ensuring footnotes are typeset at the bottom of the page. Otherwise [Harish Kumar's answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/156298/56716) seems to get the desired effect (albeit at the cost of making the float fixed), i.e., wrap the entire algorithm environment in a minipage and set `\footnoterule` to `{}`

Comment: His approach doesn't have numbers associated with the footnote though.